# how to show step by step calculation in beamer (effect of animation)

Tags: beamer, animations

Question:  I have an example of maths. My question is how can i display step by step solution in presentation i mean i would like to add animation effect.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usepackage{setspace}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.4em}} % decrease
%make new line after item
\makeatother
\title[abc University]{\textbf{Example}}

\author[Prof. xyz]{}
\date[\today]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}
%\setstretch{2.5}
\begin{align*}
x^2 -2x-15 &=0&\\[8pt]
x^2-5x+3x-15&=0&\\[8pt]
x(x-5)+3(x-5)&=0&\\[8pt]
(x-5)(x+3)&=0&
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `amsmath` environments like `align` do not work with `\pause`. But you do not need them here either, a simple `array` does the job. So all you need to do then is to add `\pause` wherever appropriate. (I also added `fleqn` because this looks IMHO cleaner.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usepackage{setspace}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.4em}} % decrease
%make new line after item
\makeatother
\title[abc University]{\textbf{Example}}

\author[Prof. xyz]{}
\date[\today]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Equations revealed step by step}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}r @{{}={}} l@{}} 
x^2 -2x-15 &0\pause\\[8pt]
x^2-5x+3x-15&0\pause\\[8pt]
x(x-5)+3(x-5)&0\pause\\[8pt]
(x-5)(x+3)&0
\end{array}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An automatic animation can be obtained with `\animate`. The time the `n`th overlay is on display is set by `\transduration<n>{...}`, where `...` is the time in seconds. This animation will play from overlay 2 on when viewed with Acrobat Reader in fullscreen mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usepackage{setspace}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.4em}} % decrease
%make new line after item
\makeatother
\title[abc University]{\textbf{Example}}

\author[Prof. xyz]{}
\date[\today]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Equations revealed step by step}
\animate<2-5>
\transduration<2>{2}%
\transduration<3>{4}%
\transduration<4>{6}%
\[
\begin{array}{@{}r @{{}={}} l@{}} 
x^2 -2x-15 &0\pause\\[8pt]
x^2-5x+3x-15&0\pause\\[8pt]
x(x-5)+3(x-5)&0\pause\\[8pt]
(x-5)(x+3)&0
\end{array}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, once again you come forward for replying my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Suppose I want to stop at any line for 2 or 3 minutes is it possible?

Comment: @Maths4Sandy Ah, I thought this is a presentation in which you press a key when you want to see the next step. If you want to have an automatic animation, you could could use the `\animate` facility of beamer and use `\transduration`. I added an example.

Comment: I want to ask one question for answer 1, why all step comes in next slide? Is it possible that all steps appear in a single slide..

Comment: Please, my humble request to you reply me.

Comment: @Maths4Sandy If you remove the `\pause` commands, there will be no steps. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I am simply asking that whatever you show in above pic, is it possible that all 4 steps come on by one on a single slide? Because when i compile your answer i got 4 slides for this.

Comment: @Maths4Sandy This is how overlays on beamer work: technically these are several slides, however, when you present them, they look like an animation. You can use the `animate` package, where this is a bit hidden, but again it produces some pdf file for each step.

Comment: Thanks for answering me.